# Apache Virtual Host in Windows - how do I deal with Symbolic links?

Tags: windows, apache, symlink

I'm trying to run a virtual host on a **WAPP** stack.  My virtual host has the `FollowSymLinks` option, but in Windows, all those symbolic links (I'm using shortcuts, and I think this may be the problem) have the `.lnk` extension.  So if I'm trying to access `settings.html`, Apache can't find it because all i have sitting there is `settings.html.lnk`.  Apologies if my question is unclear.

Comment: symlinks are not shortcuts (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link#Shortcuts).
This is more suited for superuser

Comment: You are correct.  So does anyone know how to implement a symlink for files in Windows?  Or am I S.O.L.?

Answer (score 12):

Apache doesn't understand shortcuts. You need to use a proper symlink. On windows this is accomplished using the command line tool `mklink`. See http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/ for more details.

Comment: I made them with `/D`, still it does not work, I got 403. The `/H` is good only for files, the `/J` or a shortcut gives 404. https://superuser.com/questions/1681092/apache-does-not-follow-symlinks-on-windows-403-forbidden

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons, symlinks aren't followed by default on Apache.

Better than enable it in the config file with "Options FollowSymLinks" you should use

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/urlmapping.html#outside

That's not exactly the answer you expected but may help...

Comment: I was struggling with symlinks on Linux. Could not make them work in Apache no matter what. But I tried the method for out-of-root references described in the above Apache doc link and it worked.

Comment: Further info: it works when the target is /var/web, but it fails to work if the target is called /var/reuse or /home/reuse. Perhaps "/var/web" is the only place that works for out-of-toot references? This is under cPanel virtual hosting.