# 404 Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: apache, cakephp, mod-rewrite, cakephp-1.3, wamp

I'm having small troubles and was wondering if someone can help me over the hump. I pulled a copy of a website down from Hostgator and I'm trying to set it up on my local machine using  `WAMP` but, I keep getting an error when trying to access the site. Here is what I have tried..I went to Apaches `httpd.conf` file and uncommented the # from `LoadModule` rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. Also I have changed the AllowOverride None to All. With that said, Im not sure what else to look for. Please note within my application my `httaccess` files do not have a `(.)` in front of them `(.htaccess)`. I'm not sure if that is worth noting or not. Any ideas as to what I need to do to access my site? When I access the application I do see a cached version (white screen), but when I click the link to log in I see the `404 Not Found`.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access and what file do you want it to pull up? The dot in `.htaccess` is required  http://smartwebdeveloper.com/apache/htaccess-problems

Comment: I am trying to access my login page Slic/users/login. I want it to pull up the login view.

Comment: Ok I got it. I had to go and rename all the .htaccess files. The 1st one being in www\Slic\.htaccess. The next one was in www\Slic\app\.htaccess. The last was in www\Slic\app\webroot\.htaccess

Comment: Thanks for that article you posted!! It got me over the hump!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The requested URL /about was not found on this server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149418/the-requested-url-about-was-not-found-on-this-server)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In httpd.conf file you need to remove #

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

after removing # line will look like this:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

I am sure your issue will be solved...

Comment: On Ubuntu the main Apache configuration file is actually `apache2.conf` . At directory: `/etc/apache2/`

Comment: @DoNhuVy in ubuntu, add `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` to apache.conf?

Comment: @QiankunSU , I think in this case: `apache2.conf`. Sorry, current I don't use Ubuntu.

Comment: My MAMP have that uncomment already, and I still see that error `The requested URL /login was not found on this server.`

Comment: I am new to server part.  I cannot find httpd.conf file on ubuntu. Where to add that line?

Comment: In the newer versions of apache2 it's 
a2enmode rewrite

Answer (score 44):

In Ubuntu I did not found `httpd.conf`, It may not exit longer now.
Edit in `apache2.conf` file working for me.

```
cd /etc/apache2
sudo gedit apache2.conf
```

Here in **apache2.conf** change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but after making the change, don't forget execute: sudo a2enmod rewrite. And: sudo systemctl restart apache2.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! Doing the sudo a2enmod rewrite. And: sudo systemctl restart apache2 after it, obviously

Comment: Thanks this worked for me also.  After this run below commands  \n

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**
 And 
**sudo systemctl restart apache2**

Answer (score 14):

*change this*

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

*to*

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and restart all services

Comment: where i have to do this ?

Comment: This is done in apache/conf/httpd.conf but this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 13):

### i was spend lots of time in this after then i found ...solution

```
first -
sudo a2enmod rewrite


sudo systemctl restart apache2

this line depends on your apache2 version you found on your console copy and past ...

      sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf


     DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    <Directory "/var/www/html">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Comment: This actually worked, can anyone explain these permissions?

Answer (score 9):

In apache version: **2.4.41**

First, enable the apache rewrite module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

you need to change in `apache2.conf` no need to change in `sites-available`

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Original

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

To

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And restart `apache2`

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 6):

In *wamp/alias/**mySite.conf***, be careful to add a slash "/" at the end of the alias' adress :

Replace :

```
Alias /mySite/ "D:/Work/Web/mySite/www"
```

By :

```
Alias /mySite/ "D:/Work/Web/mySite/www/"
```

Or the index.php is not read correctly.

Answer (score 6):

If your .htaccess file is ok and the problem persist try to make the AllowOverride directive enabled in your httpd.conf. If the AllowOverride directive is set to None in your Apache httpd.config file, then .htaccess files are completely ignored. 
Example of enabled AllowOverride directive in httpd.config:

```
 <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    **AllowOverride All**
 </Directory>
```

Therefor restart your server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24497749/httpd-conf-allowoverride-all

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I still get  `The requested URL /login was not found on this server. `

Comment: restart the server after the modification

Comment: I did. And I still see that error and I declare that route on my application already.

Answer (score 1):

For saving a file as .htaccess, when using windows, you have to open notepad and then saveas .htaccess as windows does not create files starting with a dot. That should get your .htaccess working and it'll clear up the issue.

By the way, in order to receive specific error messages set `Configure::write('debug', 0); to '2' in app/config/core.php` for development purposes.

Comment: What I did to rename my .htaccess was open my command prompt and execute the following. Rename c:\wamp\www\app\htaccess.txt .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this problem! I know the question is quite old, but I just had this same problem and none of the answers above helped to solve it.

Assuming the [actual domain name you want to use is specified](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-xp-tips/edit-hosts-file/) in your `c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and your configurations in `apache\conf\httpd.conf` and `apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhots.conf` are right, your problem might be the same as mine:

In Apache's `htdocs` directory I had a shortcut linking to the actual project I wanted to see in the browser. It turns out, [Apache doesn't understand shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034860/apache-virtual-host-in-windows-how-do-i-deal-with-symbolic-links/10246035). My solution was to create a proper symlink:

In windows, and within the `httdocs` directory, I ran this command in the terminal:

```
mklink /d ple <your project directory with index.html>
```

This created a proper symlink in the `httpdocs` directory. After restarting the Apache service and then reloading the page, I was able to see my website up :)

Answer (score 1):

For me, using OS X Catalina:
Changing from `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` is the one that works.

`httpd.conf` is located on `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.

Env:
PHP7.
MySQL8.

Answer (score 1):

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

If you’re using Apache HTTP Server, you need to create a .htaccess file in the public folder that looks like this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

It will get copied to the build folder when you run npm run build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (running the server locally on windows) I needed to clean the cache after changing the httpd.conf file.

```
\modules\apache\bin> ./htcacheclean.exe -t
```