# httpd.conf AllowOverride All

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, httpd.conf

I am trying to remove the index.php from my codeigniter URL. I have apache24 with codeigniter and ion auth. The only way I can get this to work is by allowing `AllowOverride All`.

The relevant code is:

```xml
<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Using `AllowOverride None` this returns a 404 error code. Using `AllowOverride All` it works.

What are the security implications with this on a production server?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`AllowOverride` directive is used to allow the use of `.htaccess` within the web server to allow overriding of the Apache config on a per directory basis. I believe CI uses mod_rewrites to make it work correctly. That's why it only works when you have `AllowOverride All` because you are telling the webserver to allow the use of an .htaccess file which CI uses. That's the simple answer. It's not about security per say, it's for the use of `.htaccess` files.

You will most likely have to use `AllowOverride All` to use codeigniter because that's the way it works. There shouldn't be any major security concerns with using this directive. Security wise you should be fine. Just **don't** use `AllowOverride All` in a `<Directory />` block.

Only use it in a specific web directory only. This below is what you have now and should be fine with `AllowOverride All`.

`<Directory "c:/Apache24/htdocs">`

if it wasn't for this directive, `.htaccess` files would not work. Have a look at the documentation for more detailed explanation.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: What are the implications of using the `AllowOverride All` in `<Directory />` block?

Comment: @ApurvaKunkulol That would permit Apache to search for `.htaccess` files all the way up to the server root. Apart from being unnecessary, the Apache docs specifically warn against this for "security and performance" reasons.