# The requested URL /save was not found on this server in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss

I am trying to save a data in DB through spring MVC. when I hit save button it redirects me to a page where the error is as follows:

> The requested URL /save was not found on this server.

Same code is working on DEV on localhost, I think there is some problem with standalone

In `Controller.java`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/save", params="save")     
public ModelAndView save(@RequestParam("save") String save) {.....}
```

The save pages updates/delete the data from data base

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853066/404-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server

Comment: You could increase your chances of getting an answer by posting a simplified example of how you configured your /save url mapping

Comment: @Gary the same code is working fine on local system of my and my colleagues but not working on server.

Comment: I would check the startup log file and look for Spring RequestMappingHandlerMapping lines matching "Mapped".  Do you see your /save url there?

Comment: Also - I assume you are deploying this application as a war file to Jboss?  If so, how is that context configured?

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if your application is actually deployed, but just at a URL you don't expect.  It is quite common for app servers to add a context url with the name of the war file.  For example, if you war file is named `myapp.war`, your `/save` url might be visible like

`http://www.example.com/myapp/save`

Comment: If i deploy same war file in testing or development environment it works fine. the jBoss settings are same, i reconfigured it twice onlu standalone.xml differs. in code i have mentioned timeout as 15  <session-config>
     <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>
 </session-config>

Comment: Do you see evidence in the log file that your application started up? i..e the /save url is mapped?

Answer (score 1):

may be your Spring web application doesn't deploy correctly. please follow this [link](http://websystique.com/misc/how-to-setup-tomcat-with-eclipse/).

Comment: The code is working fine on local system, its not working on server. I tried your answer but still no success

Answer (score 0):

```
id: my-service
    uri: ${param.url}
    predicates:
        - Path=/storage/**
    filters:
        - RewritePath=/storage/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

i also use this method but it just work on localhost, in server it doesnt work