# Failed to upload file org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed

Tags: apache, jenkins, https, artifactory

we are using jenkins 2.346 and upgrading to artifactory-oss-7.77.6 with apache httpd configuration to run on https
URL : https://artifactory.abc-bcg.net:8543/artifactory/libs-release-local/ which will route to https://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8543/ui/
it deploys artifactory for pipeline jobs, mutlibranch piepline but not working maven jobs , it works with maven job and deploy through http but not working through https

```
apache configuration:




ProxyPass /ui http://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8082/ui/
ProxyPassReverse /ui http://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8543/ui/
ProxyPass /artifactory http://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8081/artifactory
ProxyPassReverse /artifactory http://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8081/artifactory
    




Error in maven job while deploying artifactory:

[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ poll ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
[WARNING] Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class org.jfrog.hudson.maven2.MavenDependenciesRecorder$1; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/
[INFO] Artifactory Build Info Recorder: Saving Build Info to '/opt/app/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/poll/workspace/poll/target/build-info.json'
[INFO] Deploying artifact: https://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8543/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/com/bcg/batch/services/poll/0.0.11-SNAPSHOT/poll-0.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar
[WARNING] Error occurred for request GET /artifactory/api/system/version HTTP/1.1. Received status code 500 and message: .
[WARNING] Attempting retry #1
[ERROR] Failed to upload file
[ERROR] org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded() listener has failed: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while publishing artifact to Artifactory: /opt/app/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/poll/workspace/poll/target/poll-0.0.11-SNAPSHOT.jar.
Skipping deployment of remaining artifacts (if any) and build info.
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$deploy$4 (ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:57)
at java.lang.Iterable.forEach (Iterable.java:75)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deploy (ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:44)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.lambda$deployArtifacts$0 (ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:26)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach (LinkedHashMap.java:684)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.ModuleParallelDeployHelper.deployArtifacts (ModuleParallelDeployHelper.java:26)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildDeploymentHelper.deploy (BuildDeploymentHelper.java:60)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.BuildInfoRecorder.sessionEnded (BuildInfoRecorder.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire (DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:64)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire (DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main (Maven35Launcher.java:138)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch (Maven35Main.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:139)
at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call (Maven3Builder.java:70)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:211)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform (UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run (Request.java:376)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0 (InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: JFrog service failed. 
Received 404: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.throwException (JFrogService.java:49)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.Upload.handleUnsuccessfulResponse (Upload.java:59)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.JFrogService.execute (JFrogService.java:121)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.services.Upload.execute (Upload.java:77)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.upload (ArtifactoryManager.java:267)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.client.artifactory.ArtifactoryManager.upload (ArtifactoryManager.java:262)
```

Comment: The error "The requested URL was not found on this server" indicates that Jeniks server is not even reaching Artifactory. 

I believe this article should help to configured reverse proxy settings correctly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853066/404-not-found-the-requested-url-was-not-found-on-this-server

Also, please confirm if you are able open Artifactory on https ? Because the ports that you using do not seem to be regular ports. Hope https is working fine.

Comment: yes I am able to access on https under port 8543 , when i hit https://artifactory.abc-bcg.net:8543/artifactory/ it is routing to https://artifactory.abc-bcg.net:8543/ui 
I also changed to None to all in httpd.conf file and restarted apache still same

Comment: what I observe is after doing curl is below but on maven job it says site not found and 404 page not found : 
curl -v https://artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8543/artifactory
 About to connect() to artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net port 8543 (#0) Trying 100.226.145.830...
 Connected to artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net (100.226.145.830) port 8543 (#0)
 Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
   CAfile: /opt/app/cert/bcgSignerCerts.pem

Comment: Server certificate:
 subject: CN=artifactory.abc-bcg.net,
    start date: Nov 14 13:19:10 2023 GMT
       expire date: Nov 12 13:19:10 2028 GMT
       common name: artifactory.abc-bcg.net
       issuer: CN=bcg-IssuingCA1,DC=abc-bcg,DC=net
> GET /artifactory HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net:8543
> Accept: /
>
< HTTP/1.1 302
< Date: Mon, 18 Mar 2024 12:04:26 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.37 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) OpenSSL/1.1.1k
< Location: /artifactory/
< Content-Length: 0
<
 Connection #0 to host artifactory-stg.abc-bcg.net left intact